# CMake and MinGW w64 and windows system libraries

Tags: c++, cmake, sdl-2, mingw-w64

I start to learn CMake. I want to build my application with SDL2 library using MinGW w64. I generate Makefiles and use `mingw32-make` for building my app. But my app doesn't execute without any messages (my OS is Windows 10). First about I thought that my app doesn't see it dependecies. I try to use *DependencyWalker* and figure out next. My app doesn't see libriries like

`API-MS-WIN-CORE-APIQUERY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-APPCOMPAT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-APPCOMPAT-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-APPINIT-L1-1-0.DLL`

and many other `API-MS-WIN` libraries. As I can see this libraries lie in `C:\Windows\System32` and in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`. When I build my app I link next libraries `-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL -mwindows` and it links without any errors and *DependencyWalker* doesn't say something bad about this. Why my built app didn't see windows system libraries? My PATH environment has `System32` directory but hasn't `SysWOW64`. Maybe is problem in this?

**UPDATE**

I try add to PATH environment SysWOW64 and it doesn't help.
Add *DependecyWalker* screenshots

[one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0SEi.png)

[two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTnNt.png)

[three](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0i3H.png)

**UPDATE 2**

[collapsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QbPf.png)

Comment: How does complete output from DependencyWalker look like? Note that those API-MS are used by all the windows libraries (such as kernel32.dll) but most likely it is the outdated walker that does marks them as missing for no reason.

Comment: Does a simple Hello World app without SDL2 work?

Comment: @rustyx without SDL I biult and ran Hello World console application succesfully.

Comment: You should rather post screenshot of the collapsed view (that is first level dependencies) and focus on sdl and mingw dependencies. All those API-MS from system libraries can be ignored.

Comment: @VVT Update. As I know `mingw32 SDL2main SDL2 mwindows` have `.a` fromat and they links like static library. SDL2.dll is in one folder with `.exe`.

Comment: @VVT Now I have a guess that I have bad linkage. When I use cmake I get next log message:

`-- Found SDL: mingw32;-mwindows;D:/Developing/Projects/SDL2-using/lib/SDL2-2.0.8/lib/x64/libSDL2main.a;D:/Developing/Projects/SDL2-using/lib/SDL2-2.0.8/lib/x64/libSDL2.dll.a;-lpthread`

I have a full path to SDL2 static libraries but doesn't have full path to `mingw32` and `mwindows` and folder with this libraries doesn't exitst in PATH environment. I test this tommorow. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, no! I did a big mistake. My problem is not windows dll. I follow to [this](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/index2.php) guide. I didn't write part of code where windows are creating. My code was

```
//Using SDL and standard IO
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//Screen dimension constants
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
    //The window we'll be rendering to
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;

    //The surface contained by the window
    SDL_Surface* screenSurface = NULL;

    //Initialize SDL
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 )
    {
        printf( "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }
    else
    {
        //Get window surface
        screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface( window );

        //Fill the surface white
        SDL_FillRect( screenSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB( screenSurface->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF ) );

        //Update the surface
        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( window );

        //Wait two seconds
        SDL_Delay( 2000 );
    }
}
```

Be careful when you write code from examples:) I fixed this by adding part that I missed. Now my program works fine.