# CMAKE build gui application with MinGW

Tags: cmake, mingw-w64

I want to build gui application with SDL2. I link SDL2 libraries(`libSDL2.dll.a` and `libSDL2main.a`) but I don't know how a can apply `-mwindows` flag to my application. Without him `.exe` file of my application doesn't show window (executing have not any effect). I use MinGW-w64 my OS is Windows 10. In command line I can do this like [here](https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/cs1300/doc/mingwfaq.html#compilingandbuilding) (see section *B*). How I can apply this flag with usage `cmake`? Console application works fine.

I try next variant but it doesn't work.

```
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++ -D CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS="-mwindows"
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++ -D CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-mwindows"
```

Also in `CMakeLists.txt` I try do like this

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -mwindows")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass `WIN32` argument to [`add_executable`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_executable.html) and CMake will do this for you:

```
add_executable(target_name WIN32 ${sources})
```

Comment: Thank you! But it doesn't work for me. I think my problem have another reason. I hope that this help other peoples.

Comment: I found the reason. I did the mistake in source code. See [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50590930/cmake-and-mingw-w64-and-windows-system-libraries)!

Answer (score 0):

I basically copy-pasted the stuff, which CLion executes in the command line, and it worked:

```
$ cmake DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles" ../

$ cmake --build ./ --target target_name -j 6
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/target_name.dir/main.cpp.obj
[100%] Linking CXX executable target_name.exe
[100%] Built target tree_traverse
```

After this the executable `target_name.exe` appeared in the directory.